# Building Bootstrap 4 accordion cards from a for loop over a Django formset

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-forms, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

### Context

I'm trying to fill a [bootstrap 4 accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) with dynamically created [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) forms.

### Description

Starting from the example given [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example), I'm trying to build an accordion component a from a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) composed of an undefined amount of [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) (they are dynamically created).

I want all the the accordion cards to be collapsed, except for the first one at the initial step.

I would like one card per form.

### What I currently have

I currently have something like this:

```html
<div id="accordion">
  {% for form in formset %}

      <div class="card">

        <div id="heading_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="card-header">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" 
             data-target="#collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}" 
             aria-expanded="{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                             {{ true }}
                           {% else %}
                             {{ false }}
                           {% endif %}" 
             aria-controls="collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}">
              Form id is: {{ forloop.counter }} 
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="collapse" 
         aria-labelledby="heading_{{ forloop.counter }}"
         data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{ form.media }} # the actual content of the form
            {% bootstrap_form form layout='horizontal' %}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  <hr>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But this is buggy, my forms are displayed as collapsed cards and when I open one by clicking on it, it immediately closes.

I also tested with a card `<div id="collapse_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="collapse show"` 
after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545901/bootstrap-collapse-card-opens-then-immediately-closes-again) but it makes all cards open at once, and here it's the opposite; when I close one, it immediately opens again.

I also tried to change for both the previous cases, `aria-expanded="false"` to `aria-expanded="true"` in the header but this doesn't change the behavior in any of the two cases.

I also tried to remove `data-parent=#accordion` from the card div as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487974/bootstrap-4-accordion-does-not-collapse-cards) but with no success.

**Edit 2020-04-07**:

Instead of setting the attribute:

```html
aria-expanded="true"
```

I set it like that:

```html
aria-expanded="{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                 {{ true }}
               {% else %}
                 {{ false }}
               {% endif %}"
```

But it doesn't change the general behavior.

---

#### Info

Boostrap version is: `4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`
And Django version: `2.2.6`.